# Es posble copiar archivos de una carpeta a otra usando una lista de archivos de un excel en RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, data

necesito copiar archivos de una carpeta a otra. Pero no son todos, tengo una lista en excel con los nombres de los archivos que necesito copiar en el mismo directorio. ¿Es posible usar esta lista en un codigo para copiar los archivos especificos?
En este momento estaba intentando con:

```
setwd("E:/Soundtrap/500 hz")
getwd()  

lista1=barco_D

for (archivo in lista1)
file.copy(from= archivo, to= paste("E:/Soundtrap/500 hz/barco_D"))
```

Aqui setwd es la carpeta donde estan los archivos, lista1 es el excel la lista de nombres de los archivos. Pero no se como poner en el código que los archivos que se copian de la carpeta "500 hz" a la carpeta "barco_D" son los que están en la lista1.
Si me pueden ayudar :c

Comment: Bienvenida Giselle a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta para que ésta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. La verdad tu pregunta resulta muy confusa, al menos para mí. Trata de agregar algún ejemplo de lo que estas haciendo y de lo que buscas resolver.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, voy a reformular la pregunta para que se entienda mejor